# VS 2019 doesn't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET API using VS 2019 Enterprise. It suddenly doesn't let me connect to my SQL server. I tried both a local SQL Server with Windows authentication and a remote SQL Server with password authentication. I never had this problem until today. What could be the problem?

I am also able to connect to both of these SQL Servers through MS SQL Server Management Studio using the same authentication methods.

Error for local SQL Server and Windows authentication:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Cannot open database "myDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-PSCSGS6\MyLocalUsername'.
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

Error for remote SQL server with password authentication: (credentials are correct)

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MyDbUserName'.
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

Comment: The database you're requestion doesn't exists or your credentials don't have access to read it, that's what the error message is telling. Check the DB name.

Comment: @Alejandro You are right. DB doesn't exist. What I always did is to create my database using EFCode code first. Even if I dont have the DB, the following call: 
        public ContentDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        } would create it.

Comment: For creating the DB itself you need to connect with another DB (master seems the obvious choice) and issue the `CREATE DATABASE` command. Then afterwards you can reconnect to the new DB directly. EF probably does this under the cover.